# PHP site not working right

Tags: php, web

I am trying to make a online "bank" for me and my friends to use in games, like Minecraft. I got most of the things working, but the trade thing. The setup is that I use a text file as the storage for the amount of money we have, then call those text files from within my PHP code, but the math isn't working right.I will put a link to a zipped version of the whole site. I did start a session, and all of those things.

### Zipped file: [[GOOGLE DOCS HOSTED ZIP]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HEzOOnH6bqMGoxLUhnYUs2Znc/view?usp=sharing)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$riley = fopen("riley.txt", "r") or die("Unable to read data!");
$ethan = fopen("ethan.txt", "r") or die("Unable to read data!");
$ethanw = fopen("ethan.txt", "w") or die("Unable to write data!");
$rileyw = fopen("riley.txt", "w") or die("Unable to write data!");
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
$amm = $_POST["amm"];
if ($user == "ethan") {
 $txt = $ethan - $amm;
 fwrite($ethanw, $txt);
 $txt = $riley + $amm;
 fwrite($rileyw, $txt);
} 
if ($user == "riley") {
 $txt = $riley - $amm;
 fwrite($rileyw, $txt);
 $txt = $ethan + $amm;
 fwrite($ethanw, $txt);
} 
fclose($riley);
fclose($ethan);
?>
<p> transaction made. Redirecting to home in 3 seconds </p>
<?php
sleep(3);
header("Location: bank.php");
die();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you start the session? any errors? checking for them? form's ok? inputs too? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/fopen. `fopen()` returns a file handle, **NOT** the data in the file. you're adding together numbers that php assigns internally and have absolutely no relationship to your data-in-files, other than the php numbers tell php which handle is which.

Comment: It didn't report any error when I put <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); in.

Comment: You need to use `fread` or `fgets` to read the file Ethan. If it has only one line use `fgets($filehandle)`. Why not use database like mysql Ethan? Although I feel like overkill  for only four entries, it will be easier if you need to add more user. If you intend to use a db look directly for PDO and not mysql extension.

Comment: I could never understand MySQL, I will look into it again, but last time is was soooooooo confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referencing the file wrapper, not the contents of the file itself.

Example:
`$txt = $ethan - $amm;`

If passed, say, $10, This line of code is actually executing..

`$txt  = [file wrapper] - 10;`

Since file wrapper is not a value, you're getting your math wrong. You need to either read from the wrapper with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

OR

Just use a different function entirely. This is what I would do. I would pass these variables: `amount`, `user`. I would set `user` to the affected user's bank account (aside from my own, from the session, of course.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php

    $users = array('riley', 'ethan');
    $banks = array();

    foreach($users as $account_holder) {

        // Set the path of your file holding this persons bank
        $file_path = $account_holder . ".txt";

        // Lets set the $values[name] variable to the contents of the file
        // we also cast this as an integer, so that if empty, it will still be zero
        // I also prepended the function with @, to suppress any errors (if this bank doesnt exist yet)
        $banks[ $account_holder ] = (int) @file_get_contents($file_path);

    }

    function saveBanks() {

        // Access from within the function scope
        global $banks;

        // Loop through the banks
        foreach($banks as $account_holder => $balance) {

            // Set the path of your file holding this persons bank
            $file_path = $account_holder . ".txt";

            // Open the file, create if necessary, empty either way
            $fp = fopen($file_path, 'w');

            // Write balance to file
            fwrite($fp, $balance);

            // Close file wrapper
            fclose($fp);

        }

    }

    // Let's grab our active user, and transaction amount
    // If youre not familiar with this 'if' style, it's: condition ? value if true : value if false;
    // http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples
    $active_user = isset($_SESSION["user"]) ? $_SESSION["user"] : die("There is no active user.");
    $txn_amount  = isset($_POST["amount"])  ? $_POST["amount"]  : die("There was no transaction amount received.");
    $txn_user    = isset($_POST["user"])    ? $_POST["user"]    : die("There's no receiving bank account.");

    // Process the transaction, check for validity
    if(!isset($banks[ $txn_user ])) die("That receiving bank account doesn't exist.");

    // Adjust balances
    $banks[ $active_user ] -= $txn_amount;
    $banks[ $txn_user    ] += $txn_amount;

    // Write to files
    saveBanks();

    ?>

    <p> Transaction made. Redirecting to home in 3 seconds. </p>
    <p> New Balances: <?php foreach($banks as $user=>$bal): ?> <li><b><?php echo $user; ?></b>: <?php echo $bal; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></p>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=bank.php" />


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, Ethan, about your error reporting. Check out your `php.ini` file and make sure `display_errors` is on, as well as `display_startup_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` .. THIS IS ASSUMING YOU ARE IN A DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT. Production environments should have all errors turned /OFF/, and only log them to files.

Comment: I used a separate file per user.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush, had to leave to go to an appointment. Sorry, didn't mean to offend.